# Calculating Azure data lake gen2 container size and read/write operations

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Our enterprise has a shared data lake used by different departments. We want to calculate the size and read/write operations at a container level used by each department. From my research I believe the size of a container could be calculated by recursively scanning the folders/files and summing up the size but how about the read/write operations performed at a container level?
Please also suggest any other way to calculate the size at a container

Comment: Do you like to use azure portal to do it?

Comment: I know an estimate of the size of the container can be done through Portal while Monitor can be used to report on transaction ingress/egress metric but I am looking to do this programatically.